# Implement muti Y axis on QT chart?

Tags: c++, qt, plot, charts, qchart

I have to place 4 spines on the same chart with different Y ratios, so I need to set up 4 Y-axes.
I have read the "muti-axis" demo from QT creator, it shows a example of two Y-axis and the two Y-axis are put on left and right side.

[image: 2 Y axis Demo From QT Creator]

It's good when there is only two spines,
but when I have 4 spines, how to relocate the 4 Y axis?
Is it possible to place the 4 Y-axis at the tick point of X-axis? like the image below.

[image: 4 Axis like this]

Answer (score 0):

I used [ChartJs2QML](https://github.com/MichaelVoelkel/ChartJs2QML) for displaying charts in QML.
Below is the approach I followed for multiple y axes. Maybe a similar approach can be adopted in Qt as well.

- Show labels of all the y axes in the legend.
- Show only one y axis by default. Hide all the other y axes.
- On click of any y axes label in legend, hide the active y axis and show the clicked y axis.

Comment: Thank u, I have already implement this on QT, just similar to when you've mentioned, hide the other axes and show only one axis.